# 301 redirect priority order

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am looking to change the extension for all pages from HTML to PHP as I redo a company's website. So I'm adding these lines into the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

However, the contact, and about pages were in a folder in the old site that I don't want to put them into on the new site. So if I put the specific redirects above the generic "HTML-to-PHP" redirect, like this:

```
redirect 301 /company-information/contact.html http://www.example.com/contact.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Will that redirect the contact page before it even looks at the generic redirect or does it go all the way through the .htaccess file and override whatever went before in the file.

Or am I getting this totally around my head and there's another, much better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment from @LazyOne the higher priority rules should go *before* the lower priority rules in the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't understand why you want to *change* the suffix of filenames for the clients. It's better & popular to simply remove it.

Second, [Apache's Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) tells the client to fetch the resource from another location by sending the HTTP `Location` header. This is a redundant/useless round-trip.

It's better to use the rewriting rules to provide the user a different content, try:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} =/company-information/contact.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /contact.php [L]
```

Comment: As a preference I prefer to see the file extension as a user to know that I'm on a page rather than in a directory when I'm looking at the URL.  Secondly, I need to use 301s to maintain our good SEO so if I used the rewrite rules you've suggested there but suffixed with `[R=301, L]` where do I need to put that line in relation to the generic rewriting rule for the other pages so that it doesn't redirect the user to /company-information/contact.php using the generic rule?

Comment: @Dor Why do you need 2 lines (RewriteRule & RewriteCond) when you can do the same with a single RewriteRule line?

Comment: @richieahb Such specific rule should be placed **before** generic rule.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne - if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Dor `RewriteRule ^company-information/contact\.html$ /contact.php [L]` (that's if placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed else where some small tweaking may be required).